# How to detect when optional ByRef parameter was not passed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to detect whether an opational parameter was passed but for some reason all the usual functions (IsMissing()/IsEmpty()/IsNull()) always return false.

This is what I'm trying:

```
Public Sub SetValue(Key As String, Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If IsMissing(ws) Or IsEmpty(ws) Or IsNull(ws) Then
        ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    End If
```

I also tried setting the ws to Nothing or Null but the result was the same:

```
Public Sub SetValue(Key As String, Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet = Nothing)
    If IsMissing(ws) Or IsEmpty(ws) Or IsNull(ws) Then
        ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    End If
```

Any idea why this might be happenning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Is Nothing`:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        
    ' Call the sub both ways.
    SetValue "a"
    SetValue "a", ws
End Sub

Public Sub SetValue(Key As String, Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        ' We got no sheet
        MsgBox "We got no sheet"
    End If

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ' We got a sheet
        MsgBox ws.name
        MsgBox "We got a sheet"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The construction Is Nothing will work. I use it in all my parameters.

```
Public Sub SetValue(ByRef Key As String, _
                    Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet = Nothing)

    'Make sure we have the object
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: +1 because this answer is better, cannot work with a ws empty later on. I usualy set it by default to `activesheet` for sub's/functions supposed to work anywhere.

Comment: Same here Patrick I always set my optional sheet to Activesheet and I ensure it works everywhere.